# Client registration and login page with Identity server 4

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

I have three client applications using asp.net web form. I want to use current login page included in these applications and want to post the username and password to identity server for login. Does openidconnect gives facility to send username and password from client to server? Or can we send it part of access token.

Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send it as a part of access_token? You shouldnt get the access token without beeing authenticated.

You can use the [Resource Owner Password](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html#resource-owner-password) grant type if you want to use your existing login screens.